# blockIdx (and threadIdx) in Cuda

Tags: variables, cuda

Why is the Cuda variable 'blockIdx' called blockIdx instead of just blockId? It seems confusing since you can have both blockIdx.x and blockIdx.y, and since it's just the ID of the block, what's the 'x' all about? Same with threadIdx.

Just starting to get into Cuda and was trying to explain to someone how blocks and threads work and we both thought it was a weird/confusing naming convention.

Comment: It is like that because Ian Buck probably thought it was a good idea at the time. This isn't a serious programming questions and I have voted to close it.

Answer (score 6):

Common shortcuts:

- id - Identifier
- idx - Index

in CUDA you talk about "block index" and "thread index", hence the shortcut Idx.